# DIV alignments using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have two **div**'s: one for logo and another for menu, they are aligned using **flex**.
When I start decreasing the screen size, menu **div** starts shrinking until some point, when one of the menu item (ABOUT US) looses alignment.
 Then logo-**div** starts shrinking until the menu disappears.
Please advice, how can I keep the menu item (ABOUT US) inline until the menu completely disappears and how can I make logo-**div** occupy full width and centered when menu is not visible?

**Screen Visualisation:**

[image]

**HTML code**:

```
<nav class="item-center flex items-center">
                <div class="bg-red-100 pl-5 py-1">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1">
                <ul class="hidden sm:flex bg-blue-200 justify-end gap-12 text-red-500 uppercase text-s pr-5">
                    <li class="cursor-pointer ">Features </li>
                    <li class="cursor-pointer ">Products </li>
                    <li class="cursor-pointer ">Services </li>
                    <li class="cursor-pointer ">About us </li>
                    <li class="cursor-pointer ">Contact </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Adding `whitespace-nowrap` class to your `<ul>` will prevent the about us tab from doing the line break, also moving your `hidden` class from the `ul` to the containing div would help with centering the logo on mobile sizes, also adding the `justify-center` class to the logo container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to resolve your problem, [check here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/trkiYOFuaj?size=650x720)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `whitespace-nowrap` class for **about us** section and first thing that comes to my mind for **logo** is to add a **minimum width** to it, and **flex grow**, so that it can't go below certain width and once the menu disappears that it grows to the full width.

Answer (score 0):

About wrapping

```
    <li class="cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap">About us </li>
```

and about small screen check
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-single-breakpoint
and

```
    <div class="flex bg-red-100 pl-5 py-1 sm:pl-0 sm:w-full sm:justify-center">
  <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a>
</div>
```